# Spark script cannot read "||" operator?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

The code below suppose to filter the data contains string x or y. It works fine in spark shell, but when I run the script in bash it only finds the data contains y and ignored x.

`val targetData= Namedata.filter(x => (x(1).contains(x)||x(1).contains(y)))`

Anyone know how to fix this??

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
val targetData= Namedata.filter(r => (r(1).contains(x)||r(1).contains(y)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.